# 4-20mA Loop powered DAC

Tags: power, current, analog, dac

I was selecting a DAC for HART network and in the process I came across two terminology.

1. 12-/16-Bit, Serial Input, **4 mA to 20 mA**, Current Source DAC [AD5420](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5410_5420.pdf) and
2. 16-Bit, Serial Input,**Loop-Powered, 4 mA to 20 mA** DAC [AD5421](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5421.pdf)

As per my understanding, the difference between the two terminology is, the **Loop-Powered, 4 mA to 20 mA** DAC will be powered from the input signal itself whereas for **4 mA to 20 mA** need to provide supply as well as like other IC, correct me if i am wrong.

**My question here is what topology will make the Looped power devices to get the supply from the Input signal itself and what will be the behavior of these signals?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop powered devices are powered by the *output* signal. A fixed loop supply is put in series with the device and whatever loads it is driving.

To make this work, the loop powered device drops a bit of voltage (minimum), at since there will always be some current there (usually a bit less than 4mA is okay for a minimum) there is power available for the transmitter. For example, 3.6mA at 7V drop is 25.2mW.

It's important that all the supply current (including that taken by the regulator itself) be measured so that the output current is accurate.

The power the device requires imposes a minimum *compliance* voltage (voltage drop across the transmitter). If all the circuitry can run from 3.6mA a linear regulator can be used, otherwise a SMPS converter (eg. buck) can be used to get more current (at the cost of higher voltage drop).

At some point (for example a sensor that requires several watts) it becomes impractical to use 4-20mA loop power.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to read the data sheet and see the circuits they provide: -

[image]

It's not really a question of topology, some devices have built in regulators (note the REGin pin above) whereas some need a proper regulated supply but, that proper regulated supply can be derived from the "loop" making it loop-powered too. The only difference is the inbuilt voltage regulator.

Answer (score 0):

The normal connection for the loop powered device is from the +24V loop supply to the device +ve connection, then from the device -ve connection to the Measurement input. The device steals a few volts (typically 4-7V) from the loop supply. Because the device is always passing at least 4mA, it has available some power (4mA at 4-7V) to power itself.